# Trouble execute project python in bash

Tags: python

i'm trying execute project python in terminal but appear this error:

```
(base) hopu@docker-manager1:~/bentoml-airquality$ python src/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src import VERSION, SERVICE, DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

The project hierarchy is as follows:

[Project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/octVb.png)

If I execute project with any IDE, it works well.

Comment: You can do something like `PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) python src/main.py` . Problem is that python does not look for modules in workdir, you need to tell it explicitly to do so.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but now don't work dependencies.

```
(base) hopu@docker-manager1:~/bentoml-airquality$ PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) python src/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from src.services.air_quality_predictor import AirQualityPredictor
  File "/home/hopu/bentoml-airquality/src/services/air_quality_predictor.py", line 6, in <module>
    from bentoml import env, artifacts, api, BentoService
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bentoml'
```

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd) python src/main.py` - you can do following to avoid your existing PYTHONPATH being overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpretor is right. For `from src import VERSION, SERVICE, DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME` to be valid, `src` has to be a module or package accessible from the Python path. The problem is that the `python` program looks in the current directory to search for the modules or packages to run, but the current directory is not added to the Python path. So it does find the `src/main.py` module, but *inside the interpretor* it cannot find the `src` package.

What can be done?

1. add the directory containing src to the Python path

   On a Unix-like system, it can be done simply with:

   ```
   PYTHONPATH=".:$PYTHONPATH" python src/main.py
   ```
2. start the module as a package element:

   ```
   python -m src.main
   ```

That second way has an additional gift: you can then use the Pythonic `from . import ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Your PYTHONPATH is determined by the directory your python executable is located, not from where you're executing it. For this reason, you should be able to import the files directly, and not from source. You're trying to import from `/src`, but your path is already in there. Maybe something like this might work:

```py
from . import VERSION, SERVICE, DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
```

Comment: Yea, that works, but the project is so long and it's impossile change all rouetes.

Comment: That then sounds like a separate problem.. What's so impossible about 'changing all routes'?

Comment: Because, i want that don't mind, where you are, when execute "main.py"

Comment: I'm unsure what kind of project structure you're working with if you want main.py to be executed from multiple different directories.. If you need to do this I'd recommend manually overwriting the PYTHONPATH to be something predefined. For example, `PYTHONPATH=/pre/defined/path python src/main.py` would always act as if you're in that directory. Doubt this is very good practice though...